# Variable from concatentation of variables

Tags: shell-script, variable, variable-substitution

I think this is a rather simple question but, I cant make this work:
I have a whole lists of variables eg:

```
SP60=OLA SP61=BYE SP62=TRT
```

I want to create a loop to call them in the specific number of the variable
so I thought a short solution could be:

```
for i in {60..62}; do SP=$"SP$i"; echo $SP.txt; done
```

I was expecting the outcome to be:

```
OLA.txt BYE.txt TRT.txt
```

but I get

```
SP60.txt...
```

I would like to know if there is a simple way to get this done.

Comment: Actually, the exact duplicate is [How to reference a variable by its string “name”?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/232143)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option once the variables are already initialized:

```
for i in $SP{60..62}; do echo $i.txt; done
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following `bash`/`ksh` script:

```
SP60="OLA"
SP61="BYE"
SP62="TRT"

for (( i = 60; i <= 62; ++i )); do
    typeset -n var="SP$i"
    printf 'SP%d = %s.txt\n' "$i" "$var"
done
```

It will output the following:

```
SP60 = OLA.txt
SP61 = BYE.txt
SP62 = TRT.txt
```

It uses a name reference variable `var` (declared using `declare -n` in `bash` or with `typeset -n` in both `bash` and `ksh`). It means that every time you dereference it, it will expand to the value of the variable that it's referencing.