# print variables based on iterator in for loop - bash

Tags: bash, variable

I am trying to print the values of a variable which has naming sequentially in bash.

boxes1=abcd
boxes2=efgh
boxes3=ijkl

```
for (( i=1; i<=$boxCount; i++ )); 
   do
     echo "\$$boxes{i}"
   done
```

I want output like:
abcd
efgh
ijkl

Comment: Using a nameref [Variable from concatentation of variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337113/variable-from-concatentation-of-variables/337117#337117) or an indirect reference [Use a variable reference “inside” another variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41406/use-a-variable-reference-inside-another-variable/41418#41418)

Comment: For indexed variables, use arrays: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays For other cases where you have a variable name in another variable, namerefs (`declare -n`) or indirect refs (`${!p}`)

Comment: I tried the above mentioned options, but it didn't work. Could you help further pls.

Comment: Add the exact command you tried, and any error messages, to your question. Alternatively, ask a new question about the use of arrays, namerefs or indirect variables. Using a sequence  of distinct names is not viable: every time you add another name in the series, you need to update (and test) significant amounts of code. See "Two or more, use a for", or possibly DRT (Don't repeat yourself).

Comment: Below is the command and the error:

for(( i=1; i<=3; i++ )); do declare -n var="boxes$i"; printf 'boxes%d = %s\n' "$i" "$var"; done
-bash: declare: -n: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
boxes1 = 
-bash: declare: -n: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
boxes2 = 
-bash: declare: -n: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
boxes3 =

Comment: @sandeepyashodhaShiviraju  You need to define `boxes1 boxes2 boxes3` before you declare a nameref that references them. Also `for (( i=1; i<=3; i++ )); do var=boxes$i; echo "${!var}"; done`.